# c++ template programming for detecting symmetric array at compile time

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11

For example, I have the following c++ code in the header file

```
struct Data {
    static const int N = 4;
    static const int A[N];
};
```

And the following content in its cpp file to defined the array `A` content.

```
const int Data::A[Data::N] = {1,2,2,1};
```

Is there any way to write a template to detect the array `A` content is symmetric at compile time? (probably c++11 feature supports that, but I'm not familiar with its features...)

For example, the `DetectSymmetric<Data>::is_sym` will be `true` if the content of `A` is `{1,2,2,1}` and `false` , say if it equals `{1,2,3,4}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With C++11/14, you can use a `constexpr` function:

```
const int A[4] = { 1,2,2,1 };


template<int N>
constexpr bool symmetric_helper( const int (&a)[N], int idx) {
    return idx > 0 ? symmetric_helper<N>(a, idx - 1) && (a[idx - 1] == a[N - idx]) : true;
}
template<int N>
constexpr bool symmetric(const int (&a)[N]) {
    return symmetric_helper<N>(a, N / 2);
}

std::cout << symmetric(A) << std::endl;
```

With C++14, you can write a simple for loop instead of the recursion, but C++11 had very strict restrictions for `constexpr` functions.

Comment: `sizeof(a)` == `sizeof(const int*)`.

Comment: also, I'm guessing you mean't `symmetric_helper` not `symmetric_inside` in the helper.

Comment: `const int (&a)[N]` makes `sizeof(a)` be `N*sizeof(int)` again, and avoids needless copies.

Answer (score 2):

@Dutow was the first with a working answer but this should also take care of the type deduction and able to work with any kinds of arrays.

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, size_t N, size_t O, size_t I>
struct detect_symmetric_array
{
    static constexpr bool is_symmetric(T (&array)[N])
    {
        return array[O] == array[N - O - 1] && detect_symmetric_array<T, N, O + 1, I - 1>::is_symmetric(array);
    }
};

template<typename T, size_t N, size_t O>
struct detect_symmetric_array<T, N, O, 1>
{
    static constexpr bool is_symmetric(T(&array)[N])
    {
        return array[O] == array[N - O - 1];
    }
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
constexpr bool is_symmetric_array(T (&array)[N])
{
    return detect_symmetric_array<T, N, 0, N / 2>::is_symmetric(array);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    constexpr int first[4] = { 1, 2, 2, 1 }, second[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }, third[5] = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1}, foruth[5] = {1,3,2,4,5};
    static_assert(is_symmetric_array(first), "array first should be symmetric");
    static_assert(is_symmetric_array(second) == false, "array second should not be symmetric");
    static_assert(is_symmetric_array(third), "array third should be symmetric");
    static_assert(is_symmetric_array(foruth) == false, "array fourth should not be symmetric");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of modes to do what you ask.

The following is my way.

I've modified your `Data` struct in variadic template struct; just to simplify the example.

```
template <int ... Is>
struct Data
 {
   static constexpr int N { sizeof...(Is) };
   static constexpr int A[N] { Is... };
 };


template <typename T, int P1 = 0, int P2 = T::N-1, bool B = (P1 < P2)>
struct is_sym;

template <typename T, int P1, int P2>
struct is_sym<T, P1, P2, false>
 { constexpr static bool value = true; };

template <typename T, int P1, int P2>
struct is_sym<T, P1, P2, true>
 {
   constexpr static bool value
     = (T::A[P1] == T::A[P2]) && is_sym<T, P1+1, P2-1>::value ;
 };


int main ()
 {
   static_assert(is_sym<Data<1, 2, 3, 4>>::value == false,   "!");
   static_assert(is_sym<Data<1, 2, 2, 1>>::value == true,    "!");
   static_assert(is_sym<Data<1, 2, 3, 2, 1>>::value == true, "!");

   return 0;
 }
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C++14 solution (minimal, working example):

```
#include<functional>
#include<cstddef>

struct Data {
    static const int N = 4;
    static constexpr int A[N] = {1,2,2,1};
    static constexpr int B[N] = {1,1,3,1};
};

template<typename T, std::size_t... I>
constexpr bool f(const T *data, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    bool eq = true;
    int arr[] = { (eq &= (data[I] == data[sizeof...(I)-I-1]), 0)... };
    return eq;
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr bool f(const T(&data)[N]) {
    return f(data, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main() {
    static_assert(f(Data::A), "!");
    static_assert(not f(Data::B), "!");
}
```

The drawback is that it iterates over the whole array.
It can be improved, but it is left as an exercise to the reader.